# How can I overlap fadeIn() divs in jquery?

Tags: jquery

[Here's a templated fiddle that fades in 6 divs sequentially](http://jsfiddle.net/eXgHp/).

How can I made the fadeins overlap? I want the next div to start fading in half way through the first one fading in.

Perhaps I have to split the fadeIn() into 2 fades, fade half way, then fade the rest of the way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.fadeIn('slow')` 's duration is 600 milliseconds, so what you can do is do a `300` milliseconds delay.

You should write this in a more simple way using `.delay` like below, and you can change `300` to other number to config the speed.

```
var i=1;
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
  $('#div' + i).delay((i-1)*300).fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could use `setTimeout` with a time that is half of the time used for the `fadeIn`

Comment: additional tip: right now the fadeIn time is specified by `'slow'` you can simply replace that with a number in milliseconds.